# I need platform-independent version of CharToOem. Does Boost have any?

Tags: c++, boost

I need to convert string to support multi-language messaging in my client-server app.
Can I find it in boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For platform-independent codepage conversions you can use [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) library.
Anyway, why bother using codepages at all? Use unicode.

Comment: I do not mind using Unicode at all, but I need to support my native labguage in client/server app, which is Russian. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. Can you be more specific with problems you have?

Answer (score 1):

such does not exists, since 'oem character set' is os-specific and so can't be platform-independent.

Comment: Moreover, different windows localizations have different OEM and ANSI codepages.